# 2014 Nissan Maxima Loose Engine Bearings?

Tags: engine, noise, nissan, maxima

(I apologize in advance, I don't know much about cars). I recently purchased a 2014 Nissan Maxima. About 3 months later I got an oil change and recently after, I started to hear a knocking noise coming from the engine. After having a few people take a look, one mechanic suggested that I get the oil changed from the regular oil to a thicker 1030 oil. The noise still remained constant which ruled out my mechanics theory (I can't remember his initial theory, sorry!). After that I decided to just take it to the Nissan dealership and get a free diagnostic. They told me that the main engine bearings are loose ($2,500 to repair). I do not have a warranty on the car so I do not know what to do. Many people tell me you're just better off replacing the engine. Since this diagnostic, I have been driving the car for about 4 months with no problems, (The mechanic at Nissan said, "Who knows you could drive it for another 100,000 miles). I have been trying to make a decision on what to do but always get so many different opinions. If it is the bearings, should I just replace the engine?? I welcome any advice. Thanks in advance! (**75,000 Miles on it**)

Comment: If the mechanics who get to see the car can’t make an accurate decision then we don’t stand much chance... Loose engine bearings or “worn” ? I think they mean worn as if the bearings were really loose then you would not drive it long. Have they checked the oil pressure?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'd be hard pressed to think a Nissan engine would be worn out considering its age ... unless it has had a *really hard life*. You state the oil change didn't make a difference, which leads me to believe something else might be going on. Like Solar Mike stated, it's going to be hard for us to diagnose what's going on over the internet. I'd suggest you take it to someone you trust and have them look at it. Really, it's hard to say.

Comment: You're probably right about that Mike, but I figured I'd just get some opinions on what to do. From all of the research I've done, I agree that if the engine bearings are indeed loose I wouldn't make it very far, but yet I've put about 8,000 more miles on it since that diagnostic. I have not had the oil pressure tested but I am currently having the oil changed back to the recommended oil today so hopefully they would check for that? I told them about the bearings problem.

Comment: Paulster, thank you! I have had 2 trusted family mechanics look at it and have been unable to diagnose it. They said it could be nothing but to listen if it gets louder but I'm very stressed about the situation. Unfortunately they cannot check to see if the bearings are indeed loose without having to take the whole engine apart.

Comment: It is very rare for main bearings to wear. I have had 3 Nissans, driven 2 to over 150K with no trace of engine deterioration. My daughter has abused the heck out of a 2004 Infinity( same engine) and no sign of engine distress ; so unless someone put sand in your oil ,I can't believe your main bearings are bad.